# Program closing when it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm makeing a text based game.

1. the user is asked to enter:

   - name
   - difficulty
   - skill level

However, once the user inputs the difficulty the program closes.

Any help will be appreciated.

OH AND PLEASE COULD YOU NOT JUST DOWN-VOTE WITHOUT GIVING AN EXPLANATION, NOT EVERYONE IS A PYTHON MASTER.

P.S. sorry for broken english

```
while True:
    print("Welcome to 'The imposible quest'")
    print("""



    """)
    name_charter = str(input("What's your name adventurer? "))
    difficulty = str(input("Please choose the difficulty level(easy, normal, hard): "))
    while set_difficulty==0:
        if difficulty=="easy":
            max_skill_start = 35
            player_max_hp = 120
            set_difficulty = 1
        elif difficulty=="normal":
            max_skill_start = 30
            player_max_hp = 100
            set_difficulty = 1
            elif difficulty=="hard":
            max_skill_start = 25
            player_max_hp = 80
            set_difficulty = 1
        else:
            print("ERROR, the option you chose is not a valid difficulty!")
    print("Hello" + nam_char + "/n /n Please choose your abilities, keep in mind that you can't spend more than" + max_skill_start + "points in your habilities: ")
    strength, dexterity, intelligence, perception, charm, combat, crafting, tradeing = input("Strength: "), input("Dexterity: "), input("Intelligence: "), input("Perception: "), input("Charm: "), input("Combat: "), input("Crafting: "), input("Tradeing: ")


    end_prg = str(input("Do you want to close the program(yes/no)? "))
    if end_prg=="yes":
        quit()
    elif end_prg=="no":
        print("""





    """)
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: I see `set_difficulty` referenced, but never defined. I'd say you're testing your code by running it from the File Explorer, and it's generating a `NameError` followed by immediately closing the terminal window (since the program is complete).

By the way, text RPGs are a very poor choice of project for a beginner programmer, as you end up writing a lot of English while doing very little programming. Try a puzzle game instead (like Hangman or something).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll try making a hangman like you suggest. Mostly because I noticed, that most of the game would be just condicionals and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the set_difficulty to 0 before the while loop. Also I see you are printing out big empty lines, you can also use the print("\n") this will create a newline. You can add multiple by *by number desired :

```
print("\n"*10) //prints out 10 newlines.
```